# Errors while building and running C++ code in vscode using gcc. Tasks.json file

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code

This is the code im trying to build and execute.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     cout << "Hello World";
     return 0;
}
```

i am able to compile and run it using the commands

`directory path:// g++ -g hello.cpp`

`./a.exe`

I now made a `tasks.json` file so that i don't have to run the above two commands everytime, and the `.exe` file is also named same as the `.cpp` file.

This is the error i'm facing:
[image for build error in VSCode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Ap0.png)

If anyone knows a fix for this, please help me out.
Let me know if you need the `tasks.json` file contents. I'll put them up here.

**Tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [ "-g", "${file}", "-o", "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe" ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Launch.json**

```
{
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "C/C++ (gdb) Launch",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "C:/Users/H.P/.vscode/CC++_gcc_Compiler/bin/gdb.exe",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": true,
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "miDebuggerPath": "C:/Users/H.P/.vscode/CC++_gcc_Compiler/bin/gdb.exe",
                "setupCommands": [
                    {
                        "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                        "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                        "ignoreFailures": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Well, the error says "No such file or directory". So, did you check whether your file exists; and that it exists at the proper path?

Comment: @linuxartisan yes, the file exists. I am able to compile and execute using ```g++ -g hellp.cpp``` and ```./a.exe``` commands successfully

Comment: Please provide the tasks.json and launch.json files.

Comment: @mgonnav added it.

Comment: I fail to see a launch configuration for C++ in launch.json. But putting that aside, do you still have the problem if you delete options from tasks.json?

Comment: Try replacing `"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"` with `"\"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\""`.

Comment: @mgonnav Oopsie, copied the wrong file. I've updated with the correct one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's giving the exact same error.

Comment: Do the disk e:\ and the path e:\Shiva(2)\...\hello.cpp actually exist? Because that is the error thrown. Note, not just hello.cpp, but the whole path. Because your files look just fine.

Comment: @mgonnav yes the files and the path exist. I've mentioned that I can successfully compile and execute the hello.cpp file using ```g++ -g hello.cpp``` and ```./a.exe```, so the path does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try these Its working fine on my system

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      
        {
            "label": "Compile and run",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cls",
            "args": [
                ";",
                "g++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "ans.exe",
                ";",
                // "cls",
                // ";",
                "./ans.exe"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": [
                    "relative",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

and Launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/ans.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "externalConsole":true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: PS : I m using  MinGW g++ compiler and installer

Comment: U dont need launch.json to compile and run the c++ code 

launch.json is used when u r using VSCODE DEBUGGER